# Better way to wrap components with multiple context

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Basically my problem is if you have a lot of context in your app, your app could look like this

```
<ContextOne.Provider value={contextOneVal}>

  <ContextTwo.Provider value={contextTwoVal}>

    <ContextThree.Provider value={contextThreeVal}>

      <ContextFour.Provider value={contextFourVal}>

         <div>App Here</div>

      </ContextFour.Provider>

    </ContextThree.Provider>

  </ContextTwo.Provider>

</ContextOne.Provider>
```

Is there a better way to wrap the core app within multiple context?

Note: Yes I know redux and I am aware redux does not have this issue.

Comment: It could be a single provider with values as object properties. Totally depends on what are these contexts and how they are used.

Comment: what's wrong here? what aspect do you want to improve?

Comment: @skyboyer The deep nesting is what I want to avoid.

Comment: I don't believe there is a lot alternatives. it's either composition(through nesting in JSX or by HOC like `compose` but for contexts) or inheritance(composing uber-context that works like facade for several contexts). from this point of view composition is more flexible than inheritance. and explicit composition(nesting JSX) is more clear/clean than implicit initialization by a helper function. so it's better getting use to such a syntax :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I recently encountered the same problem, and decided to move the nested structure to HOC with recursion (which generate the nested structure within) based on list of contexts, and put it into a npm package called 
[**react-with-multiple-contexts**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-with-multiple-contexts).

For providers you can use HOC called `withContextProvider` like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withContextProvider } from 'react-with-multiple-contexts';
import { ContextOne, ContextTwo, ContextThree, ContextFour } from './contexts';

const Component = (props) => (
  <React.Fragment>{props.children}</React.Fragment>
)

export const ComponentProvider = withContextProvider(Component, (props) => ([
  { context: ContextOne, value: props.contextOneVal },
  { context: ContextTwo, value: props.contextTwoVal },
  { context: ContextThree, value: props.contextThreeVal },
  { context: ContextFour, value: props.contextFourVal }
]));

// And later in code somewhere

<ComponentProvider
  contextOneVal="1"
  contextTwoVal="2"
  contextThreeVal="3"
  contextFourVal="4"
/>
```

And also the same problem applies to *Context.Consumer*, if you need more than one consumer in one place. For the same reason (avoiding of the nested structure in the code base) you can use `withContextConsumer`, which is also provided from the npm package mentioned earlier.